# What is the best way to turn the knob on a lamp automatically?

Tags: motor, circuit-design, components, servo

I've been bored during quarantine and decided to build my very first circuit that wasn't school-related. I want to make my lamp remote-control, and my initial thought is that the best way to do this is have a servo motor turn my lamp's on/off knob enough to toggle the light. I can't seem to find anything on Google that would help me use the servo motor to "grip" the knob, though, and that makes me think my approach of using a servo motor is the wrong idea.

What would you guys suggest? My thoughts went to servo motor since, like my lamp knob, it turns rotationally. I'm quite the beginner though so there's a whole world of components I could be missing that I'm just not quite sure how to search for.

Thanks a bunch!

After posting this I've done a little more searching and have actually found grippers. So I now have found something that could grip my lamp's knob, but they don't seem to have a way to rotate on their own and it doesn't look like they're made to be attached to a servo motor. I feel like I'm getting warmer, though.

Here is an image of the lamp's knob, my servo motor, and my step motor:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Servo" is a wide-meaning term. You probably have a hobby-servo similar to those used in RC aircraft. This question doesn't have any electrical design element so I'd say it's going to be moved onto another stack - maybe https://engineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I would, as a first project rather suggest that you turn a battery operated lamp on and off. This way you will be able to safely connect to the electrical circuit.

Mechanical interfaces are not simple, at least not for me. c-:

Comment: @skvery  So tap into the wiring of a safer lamp to work with instead of trying to manually toggle it like a human would? Makes sense. I thought of this but I imagine it'd be much more annoying to find my bearings in the lamp's wiring, right? I'm not quite sure how complex they are on the inside

Comment: Why not bypass with switch and use a relay contact? Saves a lot of messing around but does require extra care.

Comment: @Andyaka mind explaining in a bit more detail what you mean? I'd like to retain the original knob's capability to switch on the lamp if possible. Are you saying to put a relay on the power source and just switch the light on by closing the relay? That'd be an interesting project but also sounds kind of dangerous for my skill level.

Comment: In the battery compartment, you can insert a paper with conductive material or wires on both sides to bring out the connection.  You can also use all the batteries to supply your circuit.  _Beware_, this is not safe with mains.

Comment: @jsotola added, thank you!

Comment: @jsotola added another image!

Comment: you have not described how the switch operates ... there is more than one type available and they operate differently

Comment: One turn -> light level one, two turns -> light level two, three turns -> light level three, four turns -> off

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a 3D printed adapter to mount on the knob. Then add an excentrical mount for a small steel shaft that attaches to the servo.

Or another option would be to use a stepper motor with a gear-belt or rubber-belt, depending on the force needed to turn the knob.

Comment: Honestly I was thinking there'd already be a type of adapter available. I'm surprised I'd need to 3D print one since grabbing and turning something seems pretty common? I'll look into the belt thing; not much force is required to turn the knob. Is there a reason why I'd need to use a stepper motor and not a servo motor?

Answer (score 0):

I like @sgt_johhny's idea of a 3D printed servo mount (+1). The servo you show has 180° rotation and torque of 2.5kgf-cm

To put some numbers to it, a typical dimmer pot has:

- Rotational angle of 300°+/-5°
- Switch angle of 50°+/-10°
- Switch torque of 150-450 gf-cm
- Pot torque of 30-250 gf-cm
- End stop strength of 6kgf-cm

So if you apply a step-up ratio of 1.63:1 you can operate the pot with the servo and the 
available torque should be about 1.5kgf-cm, which is more than adequate.

You could use a pair of pulleys and an O-ring as a drive belt, and by adjusting the tension it could be allowed to slip a bit... or use a conventional timing belt. The pulley hubs and a mounting bracket would have to be customized to your situation.